# PHP на локальном сервере без интернета

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть книга по программированию PHP Дэвида Пауэрса "Создание динамических страниц". Прочитав главу "Подготовка к использованию языка PHP", я убедился, что мой веб-сайт не поддерживает язык PHP. Я зашёл в Интернет и поискал, как можно установить PHP на компьютер и чтобы файлы с расширением .php открывались в браузере (и, соответственно, всё работало).

На одном из сайтов написали, что это можно сделать через локальный сервер, в который можно установить язык PHP. А теперь у меня просьба: напишите, пожалуйста, инструкцию по установке какого-то определённого локального сервера (какой Вы мне порекомендуете) и с ним языка PHP. Всё, что я находил и скачивал в Интернете, либо не работало, либо было платно.

Comment: денвер в помощь)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно просто установить Денвер для начала `http://www.denwer.ru/`
Лучше будет поставить `VirtualBox` например, и создать виртуальный сервер.

Comment: А есть аналог Denwer'a? У меня не открывается установщик.

Comment: плюсую одновременно и идее с виртуалкой, и опенсерверу вместо денвера.

Comment: Шта? Зачем виртуалку-то поднимать? Лагать будет и мороки больше. А новичку так вообще не нужно пока к виртуальным машинам лезть ИМХО.  
Поднимай Nginx и/или Apache - заживёшь!  
Nginx [раз](http://eax.me/nginx/) и [два](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html).  
Apache [раз](http://php-myadmin.ru/learning/instrument-apache.html) и [два](http://www.cyberforum.ru/apache/thread83339.html).  
P. S. Denwer лучше не юзать - он покромсанный хуже чудовища Франкенштейна, а значит невероятных глюков именно сборки там завались.

Comment: @TheDoctor, действительно, пойду выкину вагрант и начну захламлять рабочую машину.

Comment: @Etki, Я не сказал, что виртуалка не нужна, очень даже нужна, но не для локального сервера - кто ломать-то будет, кроме себя?  
Чисто моё мнение.

Comment: @TheDoctor, я вообще *работаю* в виртуальной машине. Тут же у меня стоит сервер, но с недавних пор я все проекты стараюсь запихивать в vagrant. Ничего не лагает, проблемы только с видео-требовательными задачами.

Comment: @Etki, моя этого не знать :)  
Правда, насколько рентабельно постоянно в виртуалке сидеть?

Answer (score 4):

http://open-server.ru/ - качайте минимальную версию, вам будет этого достаточно =)

Answer (score 4):

Добрый день.
Есть очень хороший пакет для ваших целей. Называется `XAMPP`.
Содержит в себе web-сервер `apache`, `php`, `mysql`, `phpmyadmin`, и все необходимые модули.
Это для Windows.
Для linux стоит набрать в поисковике "Установка LAMP". `LAMP` - Linux Apache Mysql PHP.

Comment: Только не забудьте в скайпе в настройках отключить опцию получать данные по 80 порту, а то скайп на нем сядет и не даст http серверу запуститься.